# Making a subclass to return itself without overriding

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Say I have an interface `Interface`that has a method `aMethod()` that should return itself, but also has a default implementation. Then I also have a class `Foo` that implements `Interface` and adds the additional method `aFooMethod()`.

```
interface Interface {

    public default Interface aMethod() {
        // Some code
        return this;
    }
}

class Foo implements Interface {

    public void aFooMethod() {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Now I cannot call `new Foo().aMethod().aFooMethod();` because `aMethod()` returns an `Interface`.

Now I could obviously go ahead and override the method in `Foo`:

```
class Foo implements Interface {

    @Override
    public Foo aMethod() {
        Interface.super.aMethod();
        return this;
    }

    public void aFooMethod() {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

The question I have is if there is a good way of forcing this, that a subclass has to return itself without it having to override that method?

My best aproach is to say something like this:

```
interface Interface<I extends Interface<I>> {

    @SupressWarnings("unchecked")
    public default I aMethod() {
        // Some code
        return (I)this;
    }
}
```

But this is not what I would consider *good* as it has to use a `SupressWarnings("unchecked")`. Is there any better way?

Comment: Interfaces exist to be subclassed by potentially multiple subclasses, sometimes created long after the interface. The convenience of a covariant return type is an implementation detail of some subset of those subclasses. One option is to keep the interface ignorant of subclass implementation details.

Comment: In my case I'm creating a Vector interface. Then I have two subclasses, Vector2D and Vector3D. Because you can easily scale a vector if you have its size even if you don't actually have a fixed number of dimensions, I want to do all this using default methods. However, these chain method calls ain't work for methods that are class-specific like asking for the z-coordinate because the method would just return a Vector, not a Vector3D, and that does not have a z getter. I had to override all the default methods just to return a Vector3D which isn't really the point of having the default methods.

Comment: have you considered an abstract class AbstractVector that implements the interface, extended by Vector2D and Vector3D, that offers its concrete subclasses some some protected methods for scaling? For example, that scale an array whose size depends on the subclass?

Comment: What about 4d vectors? 5d? 42d? You'll be in trouble if a mathematician got a hold of your code

Comment: @Andy Thomas The proplem is that also Vector2D and Vector3D have some methods that they don't share, for example the cross product (returns Vector for 3D, double for 2D) or the rotation (obviously can't express a 3D rotation with just one angle) so another abstract class wouldn't really make sence because the actual classes still had to return itself using overriding

Comment: @RcCookie - Okay, so you can only call those methods on a reference of the concrete subclass type. You can do both chained method calls and have a single implementation of a common method, using **covariant return types** -- implement the guts of the shared method `AbstractVector scale()` in the abstract class, then extend in the subclasses with `Vector2D scale()` and `Vector3D scale()` to just call the shared implementation and cast the result.

Comment: Note that the `(I)this` cast in your last example is unsafe. `I` extends `Interface<I>` but `Interface<I>` (the type of `this`) doesn't necessarily extend `I`. For example, `class Foo extends Interface<Foo>` and `class Bar extends Interface<Foo>`. Calling `.aMethod()` on `Bar` and assigning that to a `Foo` variable would throw a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked a question about this very same thing, but in C#. Both the problem and the answer are still the same though: Something like this isn't possible.

The pattern you mentioned

```
interface Interface<I extends Interface<I>> {}
```

seems like a good approach at first, but falls apart as soon as there is more than one class that implements `Interface`. And the problem is not the necessity to suppress a warning, it's actually something way bigger. If I create two classes like this:

```
class A implements Interface<A> {}
class B implements Interface<A> {}
```

it will still work. The constraint `I extends Interface<I>` only forces the type parameter `I` to be an `Interface<I>`, and `A` Does implement `Interface<A>`, so it satisfies the constraint even when `Interface<A>` is implemented by `B`.

I've been trying to find ways around this, but sadly, neither Java nor C# allow for anything along these lines.